# How do I configure Google Groups topics to auto-close?

Tags: google-groups

I see a posting permission option in my Google Group that allows me to set who is allowed to "Reply To Auto-closed Topic." What I don't see is any way to configure topics to auto-close. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

On the group Manage page in Information / General information / Posting options  : 
[image: bottom of screenshot]

Posting by email cannot be enabled; if you enable it, 
the 'Disallow posting to a topic after ' option is greyed out.